# Django "The empty path didn’t match any of these." 404 error

Tags: python, django, web, http-status-code-404

while following tutorial from official Django website, below error appears while trying to run the server:

[image]

[Here](https://github.com/Ravdar/django-tutorial-project) is my code, it is very short as this is the first page of the tutorial, code is exactly the same as on their website, I have no idea why it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

In your project folder, in the `urls.py` file you have not registered any routes on the path:

```
path('', views.index, name="index")
```

Or optionally `path('', include('polls.urls'))`

This is the file in question:

```
"""mysite URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

However, if you go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls` you will likely find what you need.

Comment: Yeah, I've just figured it out, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Hey! I can see you're learning, that's great. Here's something which might help you along your journey, it's a short tutorial, and the framework is a hell of a lot of fun. Give it a shot! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbUFWkZAm8w